# Apache php library caching

Tags: php, apache, caching, mod-php

If I running a php script in Apache that "require"s a php file, is there a way that I can keep that in memory so that it doesn't need to be pulled from disk each time?

Comment: it's called op code caching, and yes.

Comment: did you do this simple search in google before ask? https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=php+cache&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use one of these php accelerators

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators